# Output all the factors of the input

Tags: assembly, little-man-computer

I'm trying to output every number that evenly divides the input (so there is no remainder).

For example: if 60 is input, then the output should be:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30, 60

I have programmed code that outputs 10 in this example: 50 / 5. But I cannot figure out how to modify this, so that I get every factor. I would appreciate some help!

```
       IN
       STO DIVID
       IN
       STO DIVIS
LOOP1  LDA count
       ADD one
       STO count
       LDA DIVID
       SUB DIVIS
       STO DIVID
       OUT DIVID
       BRP LOOP1
       
       HLT

DIVID  DAT 000
DIVIS  DAT 000
one    DAT 001
count  DAT 000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need an extra, outer loop to manage the value of DIVIS, increasing it from 1 to DIVID.

Here is how that could look in a runnable snippet:

```html
#input:60
          LDA ONE
          STO divisor
          IN
          BRZ invalid
          STO dividend

next      LDA dividend
loop      BRZ output
          STO remainder
          LDA remainder 
          SUB divisor
          BRP loop
          BRA inc     
     
output    LDA divisor
          OUT

inc       LDA divisor
          SUB dividend
          BRP done

          LDA divisor
          ADD ONE
          STO divisor
          BRA next

invalid   OUT ; zero
done      HLT

ONE       DAT 1 ; constant
divisor   DAT
dividend  DAT 
remainder DAT

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/trincot/lmc@v0.74/lmc.js"></script>
```

In case the input is 0 this program will consider it as "invalid" and output 0 and halt.

This is a quite basic algorithm, and not optimised for efficiency. Several optimisations are possible, which would make the code longer. For instance, every number has divisor 1, so you could output it immediately, and start the main loop with divisor=2 instead of 1. Similarly, once the divisor becomes greater than half of the dividend, you could exit the loop and output the dividend itself, as there are no other divisors to be found between dividend/2 and dividend.

More efficiency is achieved by implementing the [long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Long_division) algorithm.

Comment: Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: If you run it in the snippet within my answer, you'll see that for 720 it outputs 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...etc (you just have to be **very** patient because of the animation). If it is different in the simulator you use, then maybe that simulator considers numbers >= 500 as negative numbers (in 10s complement). Is it an online simulator?